# pooled model summary not showing R squared or adjusted R Squared

Tags: r, lm, imputation, r-mice, significance

I'm using imputed data (via r-MICE) to carry out some linear regressions.

eg:

```
fitimp2 <- with(impdatlong_mids,
         lm(nat11 ~ sex + AGE +
              I(fasbathroom + fasbedroom + fascomputers + 
                  fasdishwash + fasfamcar + fasholidays)+fatherhome1 +
              motherhome1 +talkfather +talkmother + I(famsup+famhelp)+
              fmeal))
```

When I call a summary:

```
summary(pool(fitimp2))
```

I don't get the signif codes / asterisks, which isn't a huge deal, just kind of inconvenient, but more importantly, I don't get the R or Adjusted R squared like I would with a regular model summary.
My output looks like:

```
term     estimate
1                                                                         (Intercept)  1.560567449
2                                                                                 sex  0.219087438
3                                                                                 AGE  0.005548590
4  I(fasbathroom + fasbedroom + fascomputers + fasdishwash + fasfamcar + fasholidays) -0.009028995
5                                                                         fatherhome1 -0.055150616
6                                                                         motherhome1  0.001564544
7                                                                          talkfather  0.115541883
8                                                                          talkmother  0.149495541
9                                                                 I(famsup + famhelp) -0.006991828
10                                                                              fmeal  0.081613347
     std.error   statistic         df      p.value
1  0.162643898  9.59499539 1118.93509 0.000000e+00
2  0.024588831  8.91003863 4984.09857 0.000000e+00
3  0.007672715  0.72315871 3456.13665 4.696313e-01
4  0.005495148 -1.64308498  804.41067 1.007561e-01
5  0.030861154 -1.78705617  574.98597 7.445506e-02
6  0.057226626  0.02733944   90.61856 9.782491e-01
7  0.012924577  8.93970310  757.72150 0.000000e+00
8  0.016306200  9.16801814  239.68789 0.000000e+00
9  0.003215294 -2.17455343 1139.07321 2.986886e-02
10 0.011343686  7.19460591 2677.98522 8.095746e-13
```

Any ideas how to get the Rsquared values to display? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried
for unadjusted r-sq:
`pool.r.squared(fitimp2)`

for adjusted r-sq:
`pool.r.squared(fitimp2, adjusted = TRUE)`

see pg. 51 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much! That's really helpful, and appreciated. I'll try that out!